# Поиск и удаление массива

Tags: php, массивы, поиск, удаление

Здравствуйте у меня вопрос по поиску и удалению. помогите пожалуйта реализовать. мне нужно при поиске  **"color"  => "red"** находил все ключи то есь в данном случае **apple** и **strawberry** и сразу их удалял из массива

```
$fruts = array (
  "apple" => array (
      "color"         => "green",
      "country"        => "italy",
      "coast"        => "10",
      "key1"   => "value1",
      "key2"      => "value2",
      "key3"         => "value3"
        ),
        "banana" => array (
      "color"         => "yellow",
      "country"        => "columbia",
      "coast"        => "8",
      "key1"   => "value1",
      "key2"      => "value2",
      "key3"         => "value3"
        ),
        "apple" => array (
      "color"         => "red",
      "country"        => "italy",
      "coast"        => "2",
      "key1"   => "value1",
      "key2"      => "value2",
      "key3"         => "value3"
        ),
        "strawberry" => array (
      "color"         => "red",
      "country"        => "russia",
      "coast"        => "6",
      "key1"   => "value1",
      "key2"      => "value2",
      "key3"         => "value3"
        )
        );
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу удалить с массива все фрукты красного цвета "red"

Comment: Не обязательно удалять. Можно отфильтровать: `var_export(array_filter($fruts, function($a){ return $a['color'] != 'red';}));`  Если же именно удалить, то достаточно обычного цикла и функции `unset();` P.S. Массив у вас не корректный. Два элемента с одинаковым ключом "apple"

Comment: Спасибо большое заработало. вариант с фильтром подошел